# How 1. git stash 2. git pull origin master 3. git stash apply, on a single command?

Tags: macos, git, command-line

How I can do this in one command on MacOSX?

```
git stash
git pull origin master
git stash pop
```

I've tried with `git stash && git pull origin mater && git stash apply` and works fine.

Comment: on a side note, you probably want `git stash pop` for the last part, otherwise stashes will keep piling up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [git aliases](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases). E.g.

```
[alias]
  spullsa = "!git stash && git pull origin mater && git stash apply"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want something more "official" than setting up a git alias, you might be interested in http://www.git-legit.org/. What you're doing is similar to "git sync".